# Does adding javascript event listener with equal operator, replaces all the previous event listeners

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have an image object in javascript, I add onload listener as follows.

```
img.onload=function1;
```

At a later place again, I do:

```
img.onload=function2;
```

Now onload, are both function1 and function2 will be called, or just the function2 will be called. Please also mention if it is browser dependent?

Comment: If you want to add multiple event listeners to a single node, use `addEventListener`/`attachEvent`

Comment: In your case only function2 will be called .. As @Shmiddty pointed out try using the methods he pointed out which can attach multiple handlers to the same event